# footable return type parser connect to database in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I'm straggling to solve this problem because I'm new in terms of JavaScript, Ajax and other web languages but I knew stackoverflow help me to solve this problem by your kindness... here is the code...

view table.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
<title>tables</title>
 <meta name="viewport" content = "width = device-width, initial-scale = 1.0,    minimum-scale = 1.0, maximum-scale = 1.0, user-scalable = no" />
  <link href="css/footable-0.1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
 <link href="css/footable.editable-1.0.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/> 
  <script  src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="js/footable.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="js/footable.filter.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="js/footable.editable.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
   $('table').footable();

    $('.clear-filter').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('table').trigger('footable_clear_filter');
    });

    //Demo to mimic sending data from a server to footable in response to a command sent by the client.

    //Data records from your server
    var dataRecords = new Array();

    var dataRecord1 = {};
    dataRecord1.FirstName = "Isidra";
    dataRecord1.LastName = "Boudreaux";
    dataRecord1.JobTitle = "Traffic Court Referee";
    //a custom parser is used to format display the data for this field. See data-return-type="JSONDate"
    dataRecord1.DOB = new Date(1983,10,30);  //'/Date(78025368997)/'; - works too when data-return-type="JSONDate"
    dataRecord1.Status = '<img title="disabled" src="images/disabled.png" />';

    //Use ftEditable API to delete all rows and add new data to our table.
    //(this process happens automatically when a valid handler is provided 
    //$('#table').footable({dataHandlerURL: 'www.myHandlerURL.com',    serverTableName: 'myTableName'});
     var ftEditable = $().ftEditable();
     ftEditable.deleteAllRows('#tblFootable');
     ftEditable.addRows('#tblFootable',dataRecords);
   });

  </script>
  </head>
   <body>
    search:<input id="filter" type="text" /> e.g. jun, elec, 1981 <a   href="#clear" class="clear-filter" title="clear filter">x</a>
    <table id="tblFootable" data-filter="#filter" class="footable">
    <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="fooId fooEditable" data-class="expand">
        First Name
      </th>
      <th class="fooEditable">
        Last Name
      </th>
      <th class="fooEditable" data-hide="phone,tablet">
        Job Title
      </th>
      <!--notice below data-return-type accessing a custom parser to format   the data from the server for display-->
      <th class="fooEditable" data-hide="phone,tablet" data-return-type="prettyDate"> 
        DOB
      </th>
      <th data-hide="phone">
        Status
      </th>
      <th data-ft-buttons="Add,Delete" data-hide="phone, tablet"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
    <tbody>

        <tr class="fooNewRecord">
          <td>First</td>
          <td>Last</td>
          <td>Title</td>
          <td>DOB</td>
          <td data-value="active"><img title="active" src="images/active.png" /></td>
        </tr>
  </tbody>    
 </table>

  </body>
  </html>
```

that code work will but the problem is how to connect to database so that the footable works with the server? sorry for my English Grammar but hopefully you understand what I mean... thanks..

Comment: yes.. the server side

Comment: Yea, the server side. What have you tried yet on server side code? Have you search SOF for "CodeIgniter and AJAX" in example?